# Revoke Certificate is requested when enable automatic manage signing

Tags: ios, xcode, certificate, archive, signing

Revoke Certificate is requested when  enable  automatic manage signing , how  to solve this  problem. do revoke  the certificate  and generate a new  one ?? where the certificate is related w[image]ith another application.

Comment: ye just revoke it, it will make a new one, it just needs your permission to get rid of your old certificate

Answer (score 0):

If you are developing the app with sharing your certificate then ask the other person for the certificate. Or if you changed your mac then you can export it from keychain with the keys and add it to your new mac, but if you don't have any access to your old system then you have to create a new one from your apple developer account.